# Python Flask weird logging behavior (kubernetes)

Tags: python, flask, logging, kubernetes, rancher

So I made a very simple flask-based app and hosted it in a kubernetes pod.

When I open the logs in Rancher, I can see this warning:

```
 * Serving Flask app "app/preapproved_limits/api.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
```

that I see as well when I start flask on my local machine.

But what I **don't see** on my local machine and **do see** in Rancher is this:

```
10.0.67.20 - - [02/Jul/2020 16:49:20] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:10.0.67.20 - - [02/Jul/2020 16:49:20] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

which gets logged every 5 seconds.
What the heck?

But the most important and annoying thing is I can't see my logs which I make with the Python's `print()` function.

Can someone explain:

- Why do I see something both in Rancher and locally (the initial Flask warning), but
- why do I see something only in Rancher (the `/health` or `INFO:werkzeug` logs)
- and why do I see something only locally on my machine, but not in Rancher (`print()`)

Comment: can you share a minimum code sample that exhibits the behaviour and your kubernetes pod/deployment configuration? The `/health` is likely to be kubernetes checking the status of your server.

Comment: @T0xicCode Hi! I downgraded my app/route to a simple `print("hello world")` but still nothing in logs. And I am sorry to ask, where should I look for the pod/deployment configuration? I have a lot of files under the `charts` folder. I must say that I have the `annotations: logcollect: true` setting in deployment.yaml. What else can be blaimed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/health` is a normal healthcheck endpoint that k8s needs.

Flask doesn't print to stdout by default because it buffers lines to make I/O more efficient. You can either call `sys.stdout.flush()`, `print(flush=True)`, set env var `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` in your Dockerfile (probably the easiest) or just use `logging` module as we all should.

You can read more about this env var [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u).

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much!!! Some real knowledge! I will try this right away (or tomorrow morning).

Comment: No problem! Please accept the answer if it resolved your issue.